# JSON handle the linkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

In my service package, I return a linkedHashMap and convert it to JSON in controller, for example:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("dataObject", JSONObject.fromObject(linkedHashMap));
return jsonObject.toString();
```

Why the order will be chaos when convert linkedHashMap to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot and  ordering of elements within a JSON object.

From the JSON specification at http://www.json.org/

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

Comment: I can't find the JSONValue, did you try to use it?

Comment: I think we use different packages

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [json-lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib). **json-lib** internally implements `java.util.HashMap` to store map values. So even if you had a LinkedHashMap in the beginning, when you `put` it in the jsonObject, you lost the ordering.

If order is important to you, I would recommend using an ArrayList; or you could bind your map entries to a key which has some ordering information.

**EDIT:**
As Maxim notes, the JSON specs clearly do not require an ordered Map. `java.util.HashMap` provides a lot of performance benefits compared to the ordered alternatives, and hence is used more often in cases where ordering does not matter.

As the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) say:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: Yes, I using ArrayList now. But I can't understand why lost the ordering.